# How to properly accept a SMTP message

Tags: vb.net, smtp

I want to set up a simple SMTP server, and I'm using Net.Mail.SmtpClient to send messages. Everything works well except the next time you send a message. As soon as the server accepts the TCP client, and then the the SMTP client throws an error. It says the server committed a protocol violation the response was OK. The exception doesn't stop the message from going through. It's just not clean and I'd like to understand why it happens.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim smtpMail As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    Dim msg As New Net.Mail.MailMessage
    With smtpMail
        .UseDefaultCredentials = False
        .Port = 25
        .EnableSsl = False
        .Host = "127.0.0.1"
    End With
    With msg
        .From = New MailAddress("me@test.com")
        .To.Add("lookup@test.com")
        .Subject = "Subject"
        .Body = "Body"
    End With
    smtpMail.Send(msg)
End Sub
```

My server goes through after the above Sub is run:

1. EHLO ("250 OK")
2. MAIL ("250 OK")
3. RCPT ("250 OK" upon user found.)
4. DATA ("354 Start mail input; end with .")
5. MIME ("250 OK")
6. BODY ("250 OK")

After the BODY command, I get no further responses.

```
        While True

        Dim handler As TcpClient = _Listener.AcceptTcpClient()


        Dim smtpReady() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("220 Test SMTP Service ready" & vbCrLf)
        handler.GetStream().Write(smtpReady, 0, smtpReady.Length)
        Dim Message As String = String.Empty
        Try
            While True
                bytes = New Byte(1024) {}
                Dim bytesRec As Integer = handler.GetStream().Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
                dta = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec)

                Dim CMD As String = dta.Substring(0, 4).ToUpper
                Dim ReturnCMD() As Byte = Nothing
                Select Case CMD
                    Case HELLO
                        ReturnCMD = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("250 OK" & vbCrLf)
                        handler.GetStream().Write(ReturnCMD, 0, ReturnCMD.Length)
                    Case MAIL
                        ReturnCMD = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("250 OK" & vbCrLf)
                        handler.GetStream().Write(ReturnCMD, 0, ReturnCMD.Length)
                    Case RECIPIENT
                        Dim SentTo As String = dta.Substring(8).Trim
                        If SentTo.ToLower <> "<lookup@test.com>" Then
                            ReturnCMD = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("550 No such user here" & vbCrLf)
                            handler.GetStream().Write(ReturnCMD, 0, ReturnCMD.Length)
                        Else
                            ReturnCMD = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("250 OK" & vbCrLf)
                            handler.GetStream().Write(ReturnCMD, 0, ReturnCMD.Length)
                        End If
                    Case data
                        ReturnCMD = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("354 Start mail input; end with ." & vbCrLf)
                        handler.GetStream().Write(ReturnCMD, 0, ReturnCMD.Length)
                    Case QUIT
                        ReturnCMD = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("221 Service closing transmission channel" & vbCrLf)
                        handler.GetStream().Write(ReturnCMD, 0, ReturnCMD.Length)
                        Exit While
                    Case RESET
                        ReturnCMD = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("221 Service closing transmission channel" & vbCrLf)
                        handler.GetStream().Write(ReturnCMD, 0, ReturnCMD.Length)
                        Exit While
                    Case EHELLO
                        ReturnCMD = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("250 OK" & vbCrLf)
                        handler.GetStream().Write(ReturnCMD, 0, ReturnCMD.Length)
                    Case MIME
                        ReturnCMD = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("250 OK" & vbCrLf)
                        handler.GetStream().Write(ReturnCMD, 0, ReturnCMD.Length)
                    Case BODY
                        Message += dta
                        RaiseEvent DataReceived(Message)
                        ReturnCMD = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("250 OK" & vbCrLf)
                        handler.GetStream().Write(ReturnCMD, 0, ReturnCMD.Length)
                End Select

            End While

            handler.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End While
```

The code probably has some redundancy/is messy. So far, this is just a test for something else. I'm just trying to get a handle on SMTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since closing the connection seemed to be the problem, adding a `Using` block around your SMTP client might be useful. `Using` acts like a try-catch and safely closes and disposes of any resource connection when it hits the closing `End Using` -

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using smtpMail As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient
        Using msg As New Net.Mail.MailMessage
            With smtpMail
                .UseDefaultCredentials = False
                .Port = 25
                .EnableSsl = False
                .Host = "127.0.0.1"
            End With
            With msg
                .From = New MailAddress("me@test.com")
                .To.Add("lookup@test.com")
                .Subject = "Subject"
                .Body = "Body"
            End With
            smtpMail.Send(msg)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `SmtpClient.Dispose` solved my issue. This sends a `QUIT` to the server, and gracefully closes the connection.